# Draw curved arrow from one edge to another (tikz picture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am working on the following tex code:

```
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=7mm]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (11,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}
{
  \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] 
   (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below,font=\small] {$\x$};
}
%\node[below] at (-5.8,-5pt) {$\cdots$};   
\node[below] at (11,-5pt) {$\cdots$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives me the following picture:

[image]

How can I draw, on the upper part of this tikz picture, curved arrows from each node $i$ to the node $i+1$, each one with the label "+1"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put the fragment into a small compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add, inside your loop, this line of code:

```
\draw[red,-latex] (\x,.2) arc(160:20:.5);
```

The output will become:

[image]

ADD: If you want this output:

[image]

the line of code to add is this one:

```
\draw[red,-latex] (\x,.2) arc(160:20:.5) node[pos=.5,above] () {\small +1};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7mm]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (11,0);
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {0,...,9}
    \draw[->,font=\tiny]
    (\x,0) to [bend left=90] node[above]{+1} (\xi,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another approach.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7mm]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (11,0);
  \foreach \x in {0,...,10}
  {
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] 
      (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below,font=\small] {$\x$};
  }
  \node[below] at (11,-5pt) {$\cdots$};  
  
  % Draw curved arrows with labels
  \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
  {
    \draw[->, bend left=30, cyan] (\x,0.2) to node[below,font=\small, cyan] {$\scriptscriptstyle +1$} (\x+1,0.2);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]